# How to Implement Server-side Pagination on .NetCore DevExpress Data Grid

Tags: .net-core, devexpress, razor-pages

I Using DevExpress Grid and .net7 .
how to implement pagination on Server Side???
this is my gird
[devExpress data gird](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlwKo.jpg)

and this is my action
[Razor pages action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5h8g.jpg)

Please tell me my mistake
And guide me in an effective way
If possible, provide an example.

tank you so much

I want this to happen on the server side
That is, before calling .ToList()

Comment: Next time dont post image... but code block

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to implement yourself, DataSourceLoadOptions have all the properties and is applicat from DataSourcLoader

```
public IActionResult OnGetGetData(DataSourceLoadOptions options)
{
  return new JsonResult(
    DataSourceLoader.Load(
      _context.TableDoctors.AsQueryable(),
      options
    )
  )
}
```